# Adding my Client libraries to my Android project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, client-library

So I have generated my client libraries from the google endpoint. But according to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android).

Do I still need to add the template endpoint module to my project  ?
And how do I add these client libraries to my project ?

Because my client libraries are in .zip format (the Backend API was developed using Python)

Note: I am developing with the Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

The client library provided the classes and methods which you needed to create the build object to consume the backEnd APIs. You said that your BackEnd API is in python, so you have to use the build.gradle file for dependencies and other settings.Go through the [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android), you will find how to create the build object from Gradle and also to generate the client libraries fro Android from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_client_library_for_android).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install Gradle by following this [link](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/installation.html)

Then secondly, you open your command prompt and change directory to the root directory of where the build.gradle is located in your unziped client bundle.

And thirdly, you run this command "gradle install"..